# Set static proxy for HttpClient

Tags: java, http, proxy, network-programming, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to write a test to test my service which uses `HttpClient` to send GET request

```
    service.logger.info("Testing GET request with param= " + "test");
    service.logger.info(service.getSuggestions(searchTerms1));
    service.logger.info("Testing GET request with param=  " + "weibo");
    service.logger.info(service.getSuggestions(searchTerms2));
```

When I am running this in my company's network, it does not work since it uses proxy.

I don't want to change  my existing code of my service, so I hope to find a way to change set proxy outside, and my HTTP client will send request using this proxy. Is there a way to do that? I am using eclipse.

Below is how I send request to get result from network.

```
private final String getResultFromURL(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException  {
            RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(1 * 1000).build();
            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            // add request header
            request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT_MOZILLIA);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            try(BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()))){
                String line = "";
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
            }
            finally{
                request.releaseConnection();
                EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
            }

            logger.debug("----result from URL:"+url +" "+result);
            return result.toString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the commandline

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the proxy in java_options as follows.

In Windows

```
set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber -Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName -Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword
```

In *nix

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber -Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName -Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword"
```